# Entity Framework and the global qualifier

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, global, primitive-types

I noticed the template for Entity Framework produced a **.Designer.vb** partial class that refers to most primitive types with the `Global` qualifier for example:

```
Global.System.String
Global.System.DateTime
Global.System.Int64
```

Now because these types are *already* unambiguous why are they being referenced in this way?  If there is a chance of ambiguity why has the template chosen to use the class name, instead of the language keyword `String`, `DateTime`, `Long` etc?

Is there an actual case where `Global` is required?